# Run this python script to open url in already open Chrome browser

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a Mac and want my Python script to open the URL in already open Chrome.

Following is the code I have tried but it is not working.

Please suggest how I can change the code

```
def main():
# Accept the URL input from the user
urls = input("Enter the URL to scrape: ")

# Configure Selenium WebDriver
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Open each URL provided by the user
urls_list = urls.split()  # Split multiple URLs by space
first_iter = True
for url in urls_list:
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Ensure authentication if it's the first iteration
    if first_iter:
        time_to_sleep = 80
        config_data = read_config('config.json')  # Assuming you have a config.json file with 'time' key
        if config_data and 'time' in config_data:
            time_to_sleep = config_data['time']
        print(f"Sleeping for {time_to_sleep} seconds to ensure authentication")
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
        first_iter = False
    
    # Extract HTML content
    html_content = driver.page_source
    
    # Extract URLs from HTML content
    extracted_urls = extract_urls(html_content)
    print("Extracted URLs from {}: {}".format(url, extracted_urls))
    
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")  # Open a new tab
    chwd = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(chwd[-1])  # Switch to the new tab

# Close the driver to stop from opening new tabs
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(chwd[0])
```

Comment: Add this line and check if it works: `options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")`

Comment: Thank you @Yusuf, this is not working.

I am getting the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: detach

Comment: that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091842/cannot-parse-capability-googchromeoptions-from-invalid-argument-unrecognized)